# Java Regex Grouping Problem

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to figure out a Java regex problem that I'm having.  This is 1.6, but I don't think that matters.  Anyway...

I'm going to have some input data like the following...

```
"Blah yadda yidda 44-Barack Obama, this that the other"
```

or

```
"Something here, there 22-Hyphenated-example.  Hi there folks"
```

Basically I want to extract everything following the number through to the trailing punctuation.  In the two examples inputs I want to extract...

```
"Barack Obama"
```

and

```
"Hyphenated-example"
```

I can't quite get the pattern I need to use.  The closest I can get is this...

```
"[0-9]{1,2}-([A-Z -]*\\b*)"
```

that, however, gives me...

```
"44-Barack Obama"
```

My code is...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Blah yadda yidda 44-Barack Obama, this that the other");
if (matcher.find())
    // This gives me "44-Barack Obama" but I want "Barack Obama".
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Interestingly, I'm using the QuickREx Eclipse plugin to test this pattern and it returns the proper value.  However, running the above code does not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the result of `matcher.group(1)`, not `matcher.group()`. The second form returns everything that was matched by the previous `matches` or `find` method. The first form is used to access individual capture groups in the regex.

Comment: Ouch!! I guess it's important to read the *ENTIRE* Javadoc!

Erickson wins the prize.  In under a minute even!!